# if condition in Python's list comprehension is not working

Tags: python

I have the following simple code in python giving **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

I want a new list with non zero values.

```
data = [11,2,0,34,8,4]
new_data = [ if x for x in data  ]
print( new_data )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this:

```
new_data = [x for x in data if x != 0]
```

Comment: Or just `... if x]`, that part of the logic wasn't a problem.

Comment: @jonrsharpe either will work, but that will also work for anything that evaluates to `True`. If we are working with numeric values, I think we should write what we mean.

Comment: But with numeric values, `if x` _is_ exactly what we mean.

Comment: @chrisz explicit is better than implicit

Comment: is this the reason for the downvotes?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but sometimes answers to low effort duplicate questions are downvoted.

Comment: @chrisz ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Phydeaux I downvoted for this answer not being particularly useful.

Comment: @miradulo because it is incorrect, or because you think no-one should answer questions like this?